# How to Use dojo dnd in different scenarios

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I am struggling with both the documentation of dojo and the information online to get to a solution for what i need, hoping for your help.

I am Implementing a DND from a grid to a source or a target:

```
new dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.GridSource(dojo.byId("songForm"), {
                    isSource: false,
                    insertNodesForGrid: false
                });
```

But i am not inserting anything in that target i am using the `onDropGridRows` listner to create my own value which is a button and insert it in another div that has a normal dnd activated (calpanel) in it:

```
   dojo.connect(formTarget, "onDropGridRows", lang.hitch(this,function (grid, rowIndexes) {

   var s = grid.store,
                        row = rowIndexes[0];

                    // html.set(dom.byId("calPanel"), "<div id='calButton_" + s.getValue(grid.getItem(row), "elementid") + "'></div>");
                    // domConstruct.place("<div id='calButton_" + s.getValue(grid.getItem(row), "elementid") + "'></div>", "ElementsCalculator", "last");
                    new dijit.form.Button({
                        label: s.getValue(grid.getItem(row), "pagename") + ":" + s.getValue(grid.getItem(row), "col") + ":" + s.getValue(grid.getItem(row), "row"),
                        class: 'dojoDndItem',
                        onClick: function () {

                        }
                    }).placeAt("calPanel");
                    if (source != null) {
                          source.destroy();
                    }

                    source = new dojo.dnd.Source("calPanel", {
                        copyOnly: false
                    });
    }
```

two problems i am facing here :

1) the songForm panel which should be only a target from a grid is also running as a target from a regular dnd source, how can i stop that from happening ?

2) the listener I implemented as shown below is listening for any DND action not just the node i supplied do you have any idea why?

```
  dojo.connect(source, "onDndDrop", lang.hitch(this,function (grid, rowIndexes) {}
```

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you as I'm still learning Dojo myself and have only used DnD once (and don't have my code in front of me).  But, perhaps I can make some suggestions that could help move you forward.  First, I've found that downloading the uncompressed Dojo source can be extremely beneficial.  You can see exactly what the code is doing which can greatly enhance your understanding.  Also, if you do that, look for a function named `checkItemAcceptance`.  You may be able to use that to determine whether or not to accept drops.  Sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: Thank you, i went through he API and the source code but it is poorly documented, or at least I can't something proper.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with my response.  I just meant for you to look at the code to see what it does, not for documentation.  I believe any Dojo DnD Source object is also used as a target.  That's just the way Dojo works (if I'm correct).  So, if you don't want a particular control to be a target, add a function to that control called `checkAcceptance` and always return false.

Answer (score 0):

An example based on my earlier comment...

```
checkAcceptance: function (source, nodes) {
    if (source intanceof yourGridClass) {   
        return true;
    }

    // You may need to use this.inherited(arguments) here
    return false;
}
```

`checkAcceptance` would go in your `songForm` code.

For your second question, I've found that to be the case as well.  I don't know why it is, but it's very easy to deal with by using `checkAcceptance` and `checkItemAcceptance`.  `checkItemAcceptance` is similar to `checkAcceptance`.  The difference is you've already determined your target can accept something from the source, but now you're checking to see if the particular item you're dropping can be accepted.

I hope this helps.